# How can i Compare this range from another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to do a custom function in google sheets. I need to Compare a name and a date x from a range of dates and names but this ranges are in other sheet

This is my code, the problem is when i try to use the range from another sheet doesn't work

```js
function btk3(Date1, Name1, Date2, Name2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Name2[0].length; i = i + 1) {
    if (Name1 == Name2[i][0]) {
      if (Date1 == Date2[i][0]) {
        return "Yes";
      }
    } else {
      return "No";
    }
  }
}
```

I also try this

```
function btk(Date1,Name1,Date2,Name2) {

var app= SpreadsheetApp;

var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

var target = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Buff da Villa");

for(var i =0; i<Name2[0].length; i=i+1){


 if(Name1 == target.getRange("B2;B101").getValue() ){
   if(Date1 == target.getRange("A2;A101").getValue()){
   return "Sim";    
   }
 }

 }   

}
```

Comment: Yes, It need to return that.

Comment: your expected result is not clear... What is Date2, Name2, what do you want to try and what do you want to return.